# How to save each line of text file as array through powershell

Tags: arrays, powershell, file-io, line, powershell-cmdlet

If I have a text file, C:\USER\Documents\Collections\collection.txt that has the following information:

```
collectionA.json
collectionB.json
collectionC.json
collectionD.json
```

I am wondering how, through Powershell, I am able to store each line in the text file as elements of an array such as..

```
array arrayFromFile = new Array;
foreach(line x in collection.txt)
{
    arrayFromFile.Add(x);
}
```

..with the end goal of doing the following:

```
foreach(string x in arrayFromFile)
{
    newman run x;
}
```

My apologies for the seemingly easy question - I have never dealt with Powershell before.

Comment: As an aside: You cannot use `.Add()` to extend arrays, because arrays are fixed-size lists (while an `.Add()` method exists due to implementing the `IList` interface, it throws an exception to that effect at runtime).

Comment: In addition to that, you can use `$myArr = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList` and add to that as they're dynamic using the same `.Add` method.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

The `Get-Content` command returns each line from a text file as a separate string, so will give you an array (so long as you don't use the `-Raw` parameter; which causes all lines to be combined to a single string).

```
[string[]]$arrayFromFile = Get-Content -Path 'C:\USER\Documents\Collections\collection.txt'
```

In [his excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52172027/361842), mklement0 gives a lot more detail on what's really going on when you call this command, as well as alternate approaches if you're concerned about performance over convenience.  Definitely worth a read if you're interested in learning more about the language rather than just solving this one off requirement.

Answer (score 40):

To complement [JohnLBevan's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52170755/45375):

[`Get-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content), as a ***cmdlet*, outputs objects *one by one* to the [*pipeline*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pipelines), *as they become available*.** (Note that a pipeline is involved even when invoking a cmdlet in the absence of the pipe symbol, `|`, the latter being required for chaining *multiple* commands).
In this case, the output objects are the individual *lines* of the input text file.

**If you *collect* a pipeline's output objects**, such as by **assigning it to a variable** such as `$arrayFromFile` or by using the pipeline in the context of a larger  expression with `(...)`:

- PowerShell **captures *multiple* output objects in an *automatically created array***, of type `[object[]]`,
- but **if there's only *one* output object, that object is captured *as-is*** (*without* an array wrapper)

However, **it often isn't necessary to ensure that you *always* receive an *array***, because PowerShell treats *scalars* (single values that aren't collections) the same as *arrays* (collections) in many contexts, such as in [`foreach`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Foreach) statements or when outputting a value to be enumerated to the pipeline, to be processed via the [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object) cmdlet, for instance; therefore, the following commands work just fine, irrespective of how many lines the input file contains:

```bash
# OK - read all lines, then process them one by one in the loop.
# (No strict need to collect the Get-Content output in a variable first.)
foreach ($line in Get-Content C:\USER\Documents\Collections\collection.txt) {
  newman run $line
}

# Alternative, using the pipeline:
# Read line by line, and pass each through the pipeline, as it is being
# read, to the ForEach-Object cmdlet.
# Note the use of automatic variable $_ to refer to the line at hand.
Get-Content C:\USER\Documents\Collections\collection.txt |
  ForEach-Object { newman run $_ }
```

---

In order **to ensure that a command's output is *always* an array, PowerShell offers [`@(...)`, the array-subexpression operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators)**, which wraps even single-object output in an array.

Therefore, the **PowerShell-idiomatic solution** is:

```bash
$arrayFromFile = @(Get-Content C:\USER\Documents\Collections\collection.txt)
```

[TheMadTechnician](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3245749/themadtechnician) points out that you **can also use `[array]` to cast / type-constrain pipeline output as an alternative to `@(...)`, which also creates `[object[]]` arrays**:

```bash
# Equivalent of the command above that additionally locks in the variable date type.
[array] $arrayFromFile = Get-Content C:\USER\Documents\Collections\collection.txt
```

By using `[array] $arrayFromFile = ...` rather than `$arrayFromFile = [array] (...)`, variable `$arrayFromFile` becomes *type-constrained*, which means that its data type is locked in (whereas by default PowerShell allows you to change the type of a variable anytime).

`[array]` is a command-independent alternative to the *type-specific* cast used in John's answer, `[string[]]`; you may use the latter for enforcing use of a uniform type across the array's elements, but that is often not necessary in PowerShell<sup>[1]</sup>
.

Regular PowerShell arrays are of type `[object[]]`, which allows mixing elements of different types, but any given element still has a specific type; e.g., even though the type of `$arrayFromFile` after the command above is `[object[]]`, the type of `$arrayFromFile[0]`, i.e. the 1st element, for instance, is `[string]` (assuming that the file contained at least 1 line; verify the type with `$arrayFromFile[0].GetType().Name`).

---

#### Faster alternative: direct use of the .NET framework

Cmdlets and the pipeline offer high-level, potentially memory-throttling features that are expressive and convenient, but they can be *slow*.

When performance matters, direct use of .NET framework types is necessary, such as [`[System.IO.File]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file) in this case.

```bash
$arrayFromFile = [IO.File]::ReadAllLines('C:\USER\Documents\Collections\collection.txt')
```

<sup>Note how the `System.` prefix can be omitted from the type name.</sup>

- As in John's answer, this will return a `[string[]]` array.
- **Caveats**:

  - Be careful with *relative* paths, as .NET typically has a *different* current directory than PowerShell; to work around this, **always pass *absolute* paths**, in the simplest case with, e.g.,  `"$PWD/collection.txt"` and most robustly with
    `"$((Get-Location -PSProvider FileSystem).ProviderPath)/collection.txt"`
  - **.NET's default encoding is UTF-8, whereas *Windows PowerShell* defaults to "ANSI" encoding**, i.e.the system locale's legacy code page; **PowerShell *Core* (v6+), by contrast, also defaults to UTF-8**. Use `Get-Encoding`'s `-Encoding` parameter or the `.ReadAllLines()` overload that accepts an encoding instance to specify the input file's character encoding explicitly.

---

<sup>[1] Generally, PowerShell's implicit, runtime type conversions cannot provide the same type safety you'd get in C#, for instance. E.g., `[string[]] $a = 'one', 'two'; $a[0] = 42` does *not* cause an error: PowerShell simply quietly converts `[int]` `42` to a string.</sup>

Comment: Thanks very much for a great answer. I've tested the .NET method and it's more than 10 times faster. 113k lines took: 0.0933256 seconds and with Get-Content it took: 1.1153968 seconds.

Comment: This answer is incredible, thank you. I learnt something today!

Comment: I'm glad to hear it, @RyanJames, and I appreciate the nice feedback.

Answer (score 6):

```bsh
$array = Get-Content -Path @("C:\tmp\sample.txt")
foreach($item in $array)
{
 write-host $item 
}
```

Comment: Good idea to show a full example. Note that `@(...)` isn't needed around the `-Path` argument, `-Path C:\tmp\sample.txt` will do. Array-valued parameters in PowerShell always also accept a scalar value (and even with multiple values something like `-Path sample1.txt, sample2.txt` would do).