# Moving .eml Files in Powershell

Tags: powershell, scripting

I have a text file with a list of .eml files I generated and want to move them to another location.  Because of the way the file was generated there are some duplicates.

The script looks like it should work.  All the Variables are at least showing correct.

```
$filepath = 'G:\APPS\temp\Eric\Chris2.txt'

$new = 'G:\APPS\temp\Eric\Rel-emails'

$old = 'C:\a\b'

$OldName = (GC -path $filepath -Raw) | Get-Unique
ForEach ($item in $OldName)  {
       $NewName = $OldName -replace [regex]::Escape("$old"),$new
       Move-item -Path $Item -Destination $NewName -WhatIf
}
```

**Error:**

```
' does not exist.
At line:10 char:8
+        Move-item -Path $Item -Destination "$NewName" -WhatIf
+        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Move-Item], PSInvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperation,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MoveItemCommand
```

Comment: you're referencing `$OldName` which by the looks of it, could be a collection.

Comment: @Abraham Zinala So I shouldn't use get-content?

Comment: `-Destination` is expecting a value of type `[string]` and what you're passing it is an array when you assign it to `$NewName` inside your loop.  A change of logic should get you squared away, think you can handle it?

Comment: So `$NewName = $Item -replace [regex]::Escape("$old"),$new` will work since it's evaluating each item in the array?

Comment: In theory, yes. Give it a shot and if you have any issues feel free to update the question, otherwise if that works, we can just mark this as a typo

Comment: Didn't work, there must be something I'm missing

Comment: I'm not sure what didn't work signifies

Answer (score 0):

1. As you are reading from a text file, the input will be a string. you will need to convert it to an array. In my own testing I used a comma as the Seperator. this is because you are using the RAW switch, as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52170755/7981809). Dropping this switch will allow you to receive each new line as a different item/object.
2. The destination switch does not have to contain the full name (path + file name). path is sufficient. Unless it was on purpose, *your method should work (with the change to $item instead of $oldname).*

Mainly the issue is item #1 with your orignal script.

With this new logic you get the following script:

```
$filepath = "D:\Downloads\files.txt" #Text file with the paths containing the comma (,) as a separator

$new = 'C:\png2svg' #New file path


$OldName = (Get-Content -path $filepath -Raw).Split(',') | Get-Unique  #first read the file, then split it to array based on the commas, then filter uniqed files.
ForEach ($item in $OldName) { #for each file
    Move-item -Path $Item -Destination $New #copy it to the new file path
}
```